# Login as specific user in fixtures in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have Autovalue defined in Schema for Collection1.

This autovalue could be set by Admin only, example:

```
userId: {
  type: String,
  optional: true,
  autoValue: function() {
    if (!this.isSet) {
      return Meteor.userId();
    } elseif !Meteor.user().isAdmin {
      this.unset();
    }
  },
  autoform: {
    type: 'hidden'
  },
},
```

When I create fixtures, I need to force userId to be set, so I'm trying to simulate that I'm logged in as Admin in `server/fixtures.js`

```
Meteor.setUserId(admins.kostya.id);
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
20150829-15:45:26.819(-4)? (STDERR) /home/kostya/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.1bxqrno++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150829-15:45:26.819(-4)? (STDERR)            throw(ex);
W20150829-15:45:26.820(-4)? (STDERR)                  ^
W20150829-15:45:26.823(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setUserId'
W20150829-15:45:26.823(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/server/fixtures.js:58:10
W20150829-15:45:26.823(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/server/fixtures.js:246:3
W20150829-15:45:26.823(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/kostya/Application/myProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150829-15:45:26.824(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150829-15:45:26.824(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/kostya/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.1bxqrno++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150829-15:45:26.824(-4)? (STDERR)     at /home/kostya/Application/myProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

any clues?

Comment: I don't see `setUserId` in `Meteor` on the server. What makes you think it should exist? is there a specific package you are using that is meant to add this? I only know of `this.setUserId` in method calls. Is your code in a method? could you put it in a method?

Comment: You're right there is no such method. I also tried to create method and to call ```this.setUserId``` got this: ```Error: Can't call setUserId on a server initiated method call```
Basically what I need is to simulate the Admin User for insert fixtures which requires Admin to be inserted. How can I do it?